# Monitor native resolution can not be set

Tags: windows-7, vga, dvi

**I have an [Acer2016W](https://www.cnet.com/products/acer-al2016w/specs/) monitor which has a native resolution of 1680 × 1050, but that resolution in not listed in the screen settings.**

I believe it isn't the fault of the VGA drivers or so, but the very OS. The same monitor was used in its native resolution under windows 7 before without problems. I have dug out information which says I should use a "classic" VGA cable, but my VGA card has no VGA port, only DVI, so I use a VGA-DVI converter. (The monitor only has VGA port.)

**What I've tried so far (without any success):**

- Refreshed all VGA drivers to the latest version.
- Installed monitor driver (which I never ever had to do on any configs of mine before).
- Downgraded to Windows 7.
- Tried different VGA cables.

I wouldn't throw out an otherwise perfectly working monitor, so I kindly ask for an advice; how to fix this?

**Additional information:**

- VGA card: [ASUS Radeon™ R7 250](https://www.asus.com/us/Graphics-Cards/R7250-2GD5/).
- Motherboard: [K9ND Speedster 2](https://www.cnet.com/products/msi-k9nd-speedster-wa6-motherboard-atx-socket-f-nforce-pro-3600/specs/).
- OS Currently Windows 7 x64 professional, but it didn't work under Windows 10 x64 professional either.

Comment: Roughly how long is the VGA cable you are using?

Comment: @Stephen About a meter (3 feet 3⅜ inches).

Comment: It's not likely at that length but have you tried changing the cable?  I know with my HDMI cable I use to plug into the TV, it's so long some of the signal is lost so it can't show the max resolution.

Comment: @Stephen I've tried other VGA cables. No difference.

Comment: This usually is a problem with the monitor drivers, which are the ones that lists the available resolutions for that monitor, are you sure that you installed the proper and latest driver for your monitor model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If anyone is interested or having the same problem, I have found the solution.**

Using a DVI2DSUB connector somehow creates empty EDID data which causes Windows to treat the monitor as a "*generic PnP monitor*" no matter what driver or type I set up for that. Using a HDMI2DSUB connector and hooking up my screen to a HDMI port somehow solved this trouble.